# A word for when something is done in a way that it intuitively should be done, but isn't common practice in any particular industry

Tags: single-word-requests, should

For example, Google's changes to their privacy policies are available to the public [here](https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/archive/20150501-20150605/). This is one of many examples where this type of practice is very uncommon, but companies should do it. Another example is that Corporate Company X keeps their systems up to date (like upgrading from Internet Explorer 8 to 11) and many corporate companies continue to use Internet Explorer 8, forcing developers to create fixes for an obsolete, unsupported product.

Comment: *Best practice* is not always *common practice*....

Comment: @Dan, thanks for summarizing the theme of my inquiry. However, I was looking for a single word whose definition is just that.

Comment: The idiom *break the mold* is often used to describe such situations.

Comment: _best practice_ seems to be the most concise term. The fact that it's not common practice is just common knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for *counterintuitive*, which suggests that a particular solution is not obviously the best until you put some effort into thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

"Recommendable" may be the single word you are looking for.  Since it is a common word, giving examples would be a waste of space and, therefore, not recommendable!